# Why unwanted character getting showed when I print a string

Tags: c, for-loop, copy, printf, c-strings

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char main[]="Structured Programming";
    char copy[30];
    for (int i = 0; main[i] !='\0' ; i++)
    {
        copy[i]=main[i];
    }
    printf("%s",copy);
}
```

In the above problem this just should print `Structured Programming`, but I'm getting `Structured Programming a`, this happens on all ide's, but not on online compilers, online compilers are working fine, can anyone tell me the reason?

Comment: The code has undefined behaviour because you are passing an array to `printf` that is not nul-terminated. If you initilialise the array with `char copy[30] = { 0 };` then it will be nul-terminated, and be a C string as expected.

Comment: It is working fine when I compile and run on my machine.

Comment: So it might. On the platforms where is "works" the array *happened* to be have a `0` in the right place to terminate the string. But local variables are uninitialised: you must explictly do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This for loop

```
for (int i = 0; main[i] !='\0' ; i++)
{
    copy[i]=main[i];
}
```

does not copy the terminating zero character `'\0'` of the source string stored in the array `main` in the array `copy`.

So the array `copy` does not contain a string. But the conversion specification `%s` expects a corresponding argument that is a pointer that points to a string. Thus this call of `printf`

```
printf("%s",copy);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

There are several ways to resolve the problem.

For example you could initially zero-initialize the array `copy` like

```
`char copy[30] = ""`;
```

Another way is to copy the terminating zero character `'\0'` in the destination array as for example

```
for ( int i = 0; ( cooy[i] = main[i] ) !='\0' ; i++);
```

Or you could output the array specifying the precision field in the call of `printf` as for example

```
int i = 0;
for ( ; main[i] !='\0' ; i++ )
{
    copy[i] = main[i];
}
printf( "%.*s\n", i, copy );
```

Pay attention to that instead of the manually written for loop you could use standard function `strcpy` declared in the header `<string.h>` like

```
#include <string.h>

//...

puts( strcpy( copy, main ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes "undefined behavior" means it appears to work. You can initialize `copy`, or simply copy the NUL:

```
i = 0;
do  {
    copy[i] = main[i];
    } while (main[i++]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`printf` function expects NULL terminated string to print. Otherwise your program could access extra bytes of string that you don't want to. It depends on environment and compiler how to react to this situation but generally it's undefined behavior. You should make last symbol of your string equal to `'\0'` to fix it.